# Why $SU(3)$ and not $U(3)$?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, gluons

Is there a good reason not to pick $U(3)$ as the colour group? Is there any experiment or intrinsic reason that would ruled out $U(3)$ as colour group instead?

Comment: Other Phys.SE questions about the precise form of the standard model gauge group: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105816/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116831/2451

Comment: $U(3)$ has 9 generators, you would thus get an extra massless gauge boson (resembling very much an extra photon) on top of the eight gluons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose that $\text{U}(3)$ was the gauge group. We can decompose this as
 $$\text{U}(3)=\text{U}(1)\times\text{SU}(3),$$

which implies that in addition to the $\text{SU}(3)$ that has eight generators corresponding to eight gluons, there would be an additional generator for $\text{U}(1)$. The latter in principle corresponds to an additional gauge boson, but a theory of the strong interactions containing such a particle is inconsistent with experiment.

Comment: would the U(1) vector boson carry colour? It would resemble a photon, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it would be a singlet under the colour group, i.e. it would be uncharged. In this sense, it would be like a photon.

Comment: I see it, but i can't prove it.

Comment: Does that mean you have a specific additional question?

Comment: yes, It's a bonus question. (=

Comment: Maybe you could post it as a separate question?

Comment: Not to be overly mathematically nitpicky, but shouldn't your direct product be a semi-direct product?  See, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group#Properties

Answer (score 3):

It would be double counting, since total phase rotations of the quark wave function are already part of the model and the photon that makes them into a gauge symmetry already exists.
The total gauge group is SU(3) × SU(2) × U(1), so the question "where has the U(1) gone" has as its answer that it already was included. In a gauge theory you can only use the symmetries that you start with and you can use them only once.