# From $U(3)$ to $SU(3)\times U(1)$ Color symmetry. There is a "gluon" photon-like?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, gluons

Suppose that $U(3)$ was the gauge group. We can decompose this as
$U(3)=U(1)\times SU(3)$,
which implies that in addition to the $SU(3)$ that has eight generators corresponding to eight gluons, there would be an additional generator for $U(1)$.

Would that generator behave like a photon? (no self interaction and no color)

Comment: Probably yes, but there is an adendum, the coupling would be the strong coupling, and thus, it would couple to electric neutral particles

Comment: It would behave indeed very much like a photon, being the $U(1)$ abelian.

Comment: Related Phys.SE question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119190/2451

Comment: @user23873 the coupling could be small and different than those of the gluons. Moreover, even allowing them to be the same  at some scale, the running is totally different: one becomes bigger towards the IR whereas feh other becomes smaller in the IR