# Is Gravity a part of the Strong Nuclear Force?

Tags: gravity, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force

In episode 7 season 5 of Through the Wormhole, they say that gravity could just be a manifestation of the strong nuclear force and that the force carrier are a pair of Gluons. Is this valid in anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are the 'color-neutral' gluons confined?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116851/)

Comment: Just to add a bit of explanation to @rob's duplicate (which I support): It is not valid, since color-charged objects are confined (i.e. cannot mediate long-range interactions like gravity), and all gluons are color-charged.

Comment: My non-answer that made me mark as duplicate was this: Gluons, which have the effect of changing a particle's color charge, don't have the right symmetries to form color-neutral pairs. [Peter Shor gives a good explanation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116851/44126) in response to another (superficially unrelated) question.